# Telegram bot not getting @mention updates from group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot in a group and until some days ago I could send messages to it by `@mentioning` it by username. Now it doesn't seem to work anymore. I can send `/commands` and the bot receives them just fine and if I disable privacy my bot can receive all messages.

Was there a change server side? How would I go about debugging this further?

In summary

```
curl -XPOST https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/getUpdates
```

returns an empty array of results after `@mentioning` my bot by username in a group but non-empty results when sending a `/command`.

Comment: There has been some recent changes in the way bots work in groups:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get

Comment: I've been reading that page, last I checked it still said that @mentions are delivered, but now that tidbit is absent. I'm pretty sure the note for May 12th in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#recent-changes wasn't there when I asked this question.